# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a database for a hospital, with tables such as Patient, Ward etc.
However, below I get the following error when I execute my SQL script.
How can I fix this error?

[image]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STAFF | Error Code: 1217. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
When I comment out DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Staff I get this error instead: [image]

My SQL script is below.
Many thanks.

```
USE test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ward;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PatientWard;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Patient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NextOfKin;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NextOfKinTelephone;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Medication;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Prescription;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Staff;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StaffPatient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Hospital;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HospitalTelephone;

CREATE TABLE Ward(
wardID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
hospitalID INT(5) default 0,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
specialism VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(wardID),
FOREIGN KEY(hospitalID) REFERENCES Hospital(hospitalID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
INDEX name(name)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE PatientWard(
wardID INT(5) NOT NULL,
nationalInsuranceNo VARCHAR(20) default 0,
dateOfAdmission date NOT NULL,
note VARCHAR(250),
PRIMARY KEY(wardID, nationalInsuranceNo, dateOfAdmission),
FOREIGN KEY(wardID) REFERENCES Ward(wardID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(nationalInsuranceNo) REFERENCES Patient(nationalInsuranceNo) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Patient(
nationalInsuranceNo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
dateOfBirth date NOT NULL,
sex VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(nationalInsuranceNo),
INDEX name(name)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE NextOfKin(
nextOfKinID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nationalInsuranceNo VARCHAR(20) default 0,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(nextOfKinID),
FOREIGN KEY(nationalInsuranceNo) REFERENCES Patient(nationalInsuranceNo) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE NextOfKinTelephone(
nextOfKinID INT(5) default 0,
telephoneNumber VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(nextOfKinID, telephoneNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(nextOfKinID) REFERENCES NextOfKin(nextOfKinID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Medication(
NHS_ID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
hospitalID INT(5) default 0,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
contraindications VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(NHS_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(hospitalID) REFERENCES Hospital(hospitalID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
INDEX name(name),
INDEX contraindications(contraindications)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Prescription(
prescriptionID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
staffID INT(5) default 0,
NHS_ID INT(5) default 0,
nationalInsuranceNo INT(5) default 0,
startDate date NOT NULL,
dose VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
frequencyOfAdministration VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
endDate date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(prescriptionID),
FOREIGN KEY(staffID) REFERENCES Staff(staffID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(NHS_ID) REFERENCES Medication(NHS_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(nationalInsuranceNo) REFERENCES Patient(nationalInsuranceNo) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
INDEX startDate(startDate)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Staff(
staffID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
hospitalID INT(5),
forename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
salary DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
position VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(staffID),
FOREIGN KEY(hospitalID) REFERENCES Hospital(hospitalID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
INDEX salary(salary)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE StaffPatient(
staffID INT(5) default 0,
nationalInsuranceNo INT(5) default 0,
PRIMARY KEY(staffID, nationalInsuranceNo),
FOREIGN KEY(staffID) REFERENCES Staff(staffID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(nationalInsuranceNo) REFERENCES Patient(nationalInsuranceNo) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Hospital(
hospitalID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
postcode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
emailAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(hospitalID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE HospitalTelephone(
hospitalID INT(5) default 0,
telephoneNumber VARCHAR(14),
PRIMARY KEY(hospitalID, telephoneNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(hospitalID) REFERENCES Hospital(HospitalID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Doesn't youre ward table creation fail because it references hospital that doesn't exist yet? You should drop FKs if exist, Drop Tables if exist, Create Tables, Create FK.. in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting here because I found the answer to my question here: [mysql drop table and cascade delete to all references to the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445188/mysql-drop-table-and-cascade-delete-to-all-references-to-the-table)

I used this code and my tables are now being created. The issue was that I was trying to drop tables that were linked to other tables with foreign keys. So by disabling and then re-enabling these foreign keys checks my tables can be created.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
drop table if exists <your_1st_table>;
drop table if exists <your_2nd_table>;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Edit: you should drop your tables in the reverse order you created them, this might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the FK before deleting your tables.
Also create the FK after the table, so you can give it an explicid name

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM SYS.foreign_keys WHERE NAME = 'FK_Ward_Hospital' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Ward'))
ALTER TABLE dbo.Ward DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Ward_Hospital] 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ward;

CREATE TABLE Ward
(
    wardID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    hospitalID INT(5) default 0,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    specialism VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(wardID),
    INDEX name(name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ward]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Ward_Hospital] FOREIGN KEY([hospitalID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hospital] ([hospitalID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ward] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Ward_Hospital]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the table cannot be dropped because of a problem with a parent row. (More on what the "problem" is later.)  A parent row is a row in another table which is referencing a row in the table you are trying to drop.  For example, in the `StaffPatient` table you have `FOREIGN KEY(staffID) REFERENCES Staff(staffID)`.  So, there are "parent rows" in `StaffPatient` which reference rows in `Staff`.

Now, for the foreign key from `StaffPatient` to `Staff` you have been careful enough to specify `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`, which means that when you delete rows from `Staff` parent rows on `StaffPatient` will also be deleted. So far, so good.

However, in the `Prescription` table you have a similar foreign key with `ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE`.  The `RESTRICT` keyword means that deletions of parent rows will be prevented. So, what is most likely happening is that there exist prescription rows which reference `Staff` rows, and are thus preventing your `Staff` table from being dropped.

One solution would be to drop the `Prescription` table before trying to drop the `Staff` table.  However, it is theoretically possible to get into circular cascade situations, where the deletion is virtually impossible without resorting to the solution suggested in the answer by Chris Rodriguez, that is, drop all foreign keys before dropping tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this Mike, however, I drop my Prescription table before my Staff table already so this did not work for me. Did I miss understand you? I also just tried to remove all my RESTRICT statements to CASCADE statements and this did not fix the issue either.

Comment: @Seiont okay, that's weird.  I do not know what to say.

Comment: Have you tried SQLFiddle?  http://sqlfiddle.com/ if you can reproduce your issue there, you might be able to receive better help.  If the issue exists without data, it is easy.  If the issue requires data to manifest itself, then you can populate sqlfiddle with sample data that cause the problem.

Comment: I tried it just now and got the error - Cannot add foreign key constraint. Thanks for your help, Mike. If I can't get it working soon I will ask my professor to help.